# WPF Label appears off white instead of white

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, label

Here is an image(s) of the label in question

[image: Here is an image(s) of the label in question]

Some things have been whited out for privacy. The About is how I would like the rest of the labels to look, and they all have the same styling yet they render differently. The Connections/Policies appear to be an off-white (They are labels) and the rest of the controls appear white (they are buttons)

Nowhere in any style am I setting the color to this off-white, the label is set to have a white foreground and a black drop shadow and it appears gray instead of white. A similar control, a button, that has the exact same styling does not have this off-white colour and appears crisp and white.

The label is placed inside of the second row of a column, inside of a stack panel that is inside of another stack panel. When I place the label outside of the stack panels into the base grid row then this graying does not occur. I am new to WPF and cannot find any sort of solution.
Below is a snippet of the label xaml in question with the extra/irrelevant infomation removed such as column definitions and unrelated controls.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">                         
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Label Content="Connections" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Background="{x:Null}"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                    <Label.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="3" />
                    </Label.Effect>
                </Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you make a simple form that replicates the problem in the most minimalist way, i would be interested in seeing the behavior your describe

Comment: It's likely that some default styling is being placed on those other elements. Use a program like SnoopWPF (https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf) or the Visual Studio WPF Tree Visualizer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-wpf-tree-visualizer) to inspect the WPF object tree and see what styles are being applied and what templates they come from.

Comment: @JohnM.Wright I inspected the Label that is not rendering correctly and the foreground color appears to be #FFFFFF with an opacity of 1, so everything there appears to be correct, The buttons all appear to be inheriting the correct style, PanelButtonStyle, and the label doesn't have a style it is just set to have a white foreground, null background, and a drop shadow effect. Is there anything specifically I should be looking for here? I don't see anything inheriting something it shouldn't.